# ¿Cómo hacer un cilindro con css?

Tags: html, html5, css, css3, css-transform

Estoy utilizando HTML y CSS para aprender/practicar transformaciones 2D y 3D y para ello estoy dibujando una pila 9v tridimensional (porque es sencilla y cuadradita). Hasta ahora todo ha sido sencillo porque sólo he necesitado transformaciones para rotar y mover las diferentes caras (rectangulares) de la pila.

Pero me encuentro con que los electrodos de la pila son circulares y no sé cómo hacer que un `div` (u otro elemento) tenga forma de circular (de tubo en 3D). Me imagino que sería "simular" un círculo utilizando muchos vertices, pero eso parece complicado.

Esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora (en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t1h817f6/)):

```css
@-moz-keyframes spin {
  from {transform:rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0) rotateZ(0);}
  to {transform:rotateY(360deg) rotateX(360deg) rotateZ(360deg);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {transform:rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0) rotateZ(0);}
  to {transform:rotateY(360deg) rotateX(360deg) rotateZ(360deg);}
}
@keyframes spin {
  from {transform:rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0) rotateZ(360);}
  to {transform:rotateY(360deg) rotateX(360deg) rotateZ(0deg);}
}

.container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  position:relative;
  width:120px;
  height:200px;
  margin:100px;
}
#battery {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-animation: spin 14s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spin 14s infinite linear;
  animation: spin 14s infinite linear;
}
.face {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transform-origin:0 0;
  opacity:10.6;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.face:before, .face:after, .face span:after, .face span:before {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transform-origin: left top 0;
  display:block;
  font-family:arial,sans-serif;
  white-space: pre;
}
.large {
  width:120px;
  height:200px;
  background:#111111;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 66px 0px #CC7722;
}
.side {
  width:66px;
  height:200px;
  background:black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 66px 0px #AA5500;
}
.short {
  width:120px;
  height:66px;
  background:#222222;
}
.top {
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 8px #BB6611;
}
.bottom {
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 8px #111111;
}
.front:before, .back:before, .right:before {
  content:"DURACELL";
  color:silver;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(72px, -68px);
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:1.3em;
}
.front:after, .back:after {
  content:"ALKALINE BATTERY";
  color:silver;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(73px, -44px);
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:0.5em;
}
.back:after { content:"PILE ALCALINE"; }
.right:before { transform: rotate(90deg) translate(72px, -50px) }
.right:after {
  content:"Duracell, div of P&G, Bethel, CT 06801 \a P&G Inc., Toronto, ON M5W1C5 \a Made in U.S.A. / Fabrique aux E.-U. \a 95756099";
  width:130px;
  color:silver;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(73px, -27px);
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:0.29em;
  letter-spacing:-0.1px;
  line-height:1.2em;
}
.right span:before {
  content:"\2b06\a+";
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height:0.8em;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
  font-size:1.3em;
}
.right span:after {
  content:"MAR \a 2015";
  color:#AA5500;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(150px, -23px);
  width:60px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:0.6em;
  text-align:center;
}
.left:before {
  content:"MN1604 \a 6LR61 \a 9 VOLTS";
  line-height:1em;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(15px, -59px);
  font-size:0.5em;
  font-weight:bold;
  letter-spacing:-0.1px;
}
.left span:before {
  content:"Caution: do not connect improperly. Charge or dispose of in fire. Battery may explode or leak. Do not carry batteries loose in your pocket or elsewhere as burn injury could result.";
  width:120px;
  color:silver;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(73px, -60px);
  font-weight:200;
  font-size:0.25em;
  letter-spacing:-0.2px;
  line-height:1.2em;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  white-space: normal;
}

#battery .front { transform: rotateY( 0deg ) translateZ( 66px ); }
#battery .back { transform: rotateY( 180deg ) translateX( -120px ); }
#battery .right { transform: rotateY( 90deg ) translateZ( 120px ) translateX(-66px); }
#battery .left { transform: rotateY( -90deg ) translateZ( 0 ); }
#battery .top { transform: rotateX( -270deg ) translateZ( 0 ); }
#battery .bottom { transform: rotateX( 90deg ) translateZ( -200px ); }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="battery">
    <div class="face large front"></div>
    <div class="face large back"></div>
    <div class="face side right"><span></span></div>
    <div class="face side left"><span></span></div>
    <div class="face short top"></div>
    <div class="face short bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

y así es como se ve:

[image: Pila en HTML + CSS, faltan los electrodos]

Me imagino que podría hacerse con SVG o un `canvas`, pero quiero limitarme a HTML+CSS3 (con transformaciones 2D y 3D). Entonces mis preguntas realmente son:

- ¿Se puede tener un `div` curvo? (**no un círculo, sino un tubo**)
- ¿Se pueden hacer `div` curvados? (p.e. para crear dos semicírculos y juntarlos en un círculo)

Y si no se puede curvar el elemento, ¿cuál podría ser una alternativa? ¿O mi única opción es simularlo como decía antes?

Comment: He encontrado esto que te puede servir: http://cssdeck.com/labs/wrap-image-in-3d-cylinder-2  He hecho algunas pruebas de rotarlo en diferentes ejes y parece que funciona bastante bien.

Comment: @blonfu Sí, finalmente optaré por algo similar a eso. Gracias por compartir el enlace

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Lo primero que debes tener presente cuando manejas transformaciones tridimensionales en CSS es que los elementos html **no tienen grosor** por lo que es **imposible** hacer un círculo, cuadrado u otra figura en CSS que tenga profundidad ya que **siempre estarán reducidos a un plano**.

En tu ejemplo la pila esta compuesta por diferentes elementos planos que juntos componen un cubo dando la impresión de profundidad precisamente para sortear dicha limitación.

La forma correcta de simular lo que quieres es con canvas que trae funciones para manipular este tipo de transformaciones tridimensionales. Te recomiendo echarle un vistazo a [three.js](http://threejs.org/)

Crear un círculo plano con CSS es muy sencillo con la propiedad `border-radius: 50%` pero lograr un cilindro superponiendo muchas capas necesitaría muchos elementos(y probablemente la ayuda de javascript para lograr simplicidad). Aquí tienes un demo.

```css
@-moz-keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg) rotateX(360deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg) rotateX(360deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg) rotateX(360deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}
.container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 100px;
}
#battery {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-animation: spin 14s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spin 14s infinite linear;
  animation: spin 14s infinite linear;
}
.face {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  opacity: 10.6;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.face:before,
.face:after,
.face span:after,
.face span:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: left top 0;
  display: block;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  white-space: pre;
}
.large {
  width: 120px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #111111;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 66px 0px #CC7722;
}
.side {
  width: 66px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 66px 0px #AA5500;
}
.short {
  width: 120px;
  height: 66px;
  background: #222222;
}
.top {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 8px #BB6611;
}
.bottom {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 8px #111111;
}
.front:before,
.back:before,
.right:before {
  content: "DURACELL";
  color: silver;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(72px, -68px);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
.front:after,
.back:after {
  content: "ALKALINE BATTERY";
  color: silver;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(73px, -44px);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
.back:after {
  content: "PILE ALCALINE";
}
.right:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(72px, -50px)
}
.right:after {
  content: "Duracell, div of P&G, Bethel, CT 06801 \a P&G Inc., Toronto, ON M5W1C5 \a Made in U.S.A. / Fabrique aux E.-U. \a 95756099";
  width: 130px;
  color: silver;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(73px, -27px);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.29em;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
.right span:before {
  content: "\2b06\a+";
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 0.8em;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
.right span:after {
  content: "MAR \a 2015";
  color: #AA5500;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(150px, -23px);
  width: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  text-align: center;
}
.left:before {
  content: "MN1604 \a 6LR61 \a 9 VOLTS";
  line-height: 1em;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(15px, -59px);
  font-size: 0.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
}
.left span:before {
  content: "Caution: do not connect improperly. Charge or dispose of in fire. Battery may explode or leak. Do not carry batteries loose in your pocket or elsewhere as burn injury could result.";
  width: 120px;
  color: silver;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(73px, -60px);
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 0.25em;
  letter-spacing: -0.2px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: normal;
}
#battery .front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(66px);
}
#battery .back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateX(-120px);
}
#battery .right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(120px) translateX(-66px);
}
#battery .left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(0);
}
#battery .top {
  transform: rotateX(-270deg) translateZ(0);
}
#battery .bottom {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-200px);
}
#battery .electrodo1 .layer1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  transform: translateX(26px) translateY(-9px) translateZ(33px) rotateX(-270deg);
}
#battery .electrodo1 .layer2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  transform: translateX(26px) translateY(-10px) translateZ(33px) rotateX(-270deg);
}
#battery .electrodo1 .layer3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  transform: translateX(26px) translateY(-11px) translateZ(33px) rotateX(-270deg);
}
#battery .electrodo1 .layer4 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  transform: translateX(26px) translateY(-12px) translateZ(33px) rotateX(-270deg);
}
#battery .electrodo1 .layer5 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  transform: translateX(26px) translateY(-13px) translateZ(33px) rotateX(-270deg);
}
#battery .electrodo1 .layer6 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  transform: translateX(26px) translateY(-14px) translateZ(33px) rotateX(-270deg);
}
#battery .electrodo1 .layer7 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  transform: translateX(26px) translateY(-15px) translateZ(33px) rotateX(-270deg);
}
#battery .electrodo2 .layer1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  transform: translateX(86px) translateY(-9px) translateZ(33px) rotateX(-270deg);
}
#battery .electrodo2 .layer2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  transform: translateX(86px) translateY(-10px) translateZ(33px) rotateX(-270deg);
}
#battery .electrodo2 .layer3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  transform: translateX(86px) translateY(-11px) translateZ(33px) rotateX(-270deg);
}
#battery .electrodo2 .layer4 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  transform: translateX(86px) translateY(-12px) translateZ(33px) rotateX(-270deg);
}
#battery .electrodo2 .layer5 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  transform: translateX(86px) translateY(-13px) translateZ(33px) rotateX(-270deg);
}
#battery .electrodo2 .layer6 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  transform: translateX(86px) translateY(-14px) translateZ(33px) rotateX(-270deg);
}
#battery .electrodo2 .layer7 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  transform: translateX(86px) translateY(-15px) translateZ(33px) rotateX(-270deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="battery">
    <div class="electrodo1">
      <div class="layer1"></div>
      <div class="layer2"></div>
      <div class="layer3"></div>
      <div class="layer4"></div>
      <div class="layer5"></div>
      <div class="layer6"></div>
      <div class="layer7"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="electrodo2">
      <div class="layer1"></div>
      <div class="layer2"></div>
      <div class="layer3"></div>
      <div class="layer4"></div>
      <div class="layer5"></div>
      <div class="layer6"></div>
      <div class="layer7"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="face large front"></div>
    <div class="face large back"></div>
    <div class="face side right"><span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="face side left"><span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="face short top"></div>
    <div class="face short bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aún así en algún momento de la rotación verás un destello cuando todas las capas del electrodo esten perpendiculares a la pantalla donde se hace evidente el truco.

[image: comparacion pila en posiciones diferentes]

Como alternativa puedes hacer un [prisma hexagonal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisma_%28geometr%C3%ADa%29) a base de planos. Mientras más planos uses más te acercarás a la figura del círculo pero necesitarás una gran cantidad de elementos para lograr esto(uno por cada lado y varios para simular una capa superior).

Comment: Buena respuesta. No es lo que quería leer, pero me imaginaba que por ahí iban a ir los tiros. Voy a intentar lo del prisma hexagonal y simular así el cilindro. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Otra forma de hacer un cilindro. Había visto varias por ahí pero con muchos `div` y montones de líneas CSS, la solución de Asier me ha gustado porque es sencilla y me ha ha dado la idea de intentarlo con un solo `div`.

```css
.cilindro {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #666;
  border-radius: 65px / 25px;
}

.cilindro:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 40px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 65px / 15px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cilindro"></div>
```

**P.D.:** Despues de leer la respuesta de @devconcept me he dado cuenta que mi ejemplo solo sirve para un dibujo estático, si se quiere rotar habría que hacer algunos trucos para simular un objeto en 3D, no parece fácil.

Comment: Como bien indicas esta solución funciona sólo en 2D porque aunque el resultado parece un cilindro, realmente es sólo simulado y es plano. El enlace que compartiste arriba (por cierto, gracias) es más lo que busco.

Answer (score -1):

Crear un div circular es muy sencillo utilizando la propiedad border-radius:

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Para el efecto de cilindro podrías utilizar la propiedad box-shadow:

```css
    div{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: blue;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px gray, 3px 3px black, 8px 8px gray, 9px 9px black;
    }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Lo probé y no me funciona porque el círculo es plano y no tridimensional, y cuando animo el elemento deja de verse. Parece que el box-shadow es una sombra simulada que se acaba dibujando en el mismo plano que el elemento en lugar de "caer" como una sombra de verdad. Si hubiera sido lo último podría haber funcionado. La verdad es que era una buena idea.